What is this usage of ことが過ぎる? (NSFW warning i guess)

そんな風に考えていると、青戸の押し殺した笑いが耳を擽った。
それはどこか獣欲めいて、初めて体を重ねた時のことが過ぎる。

The character is thinking this after her lover teases her.
"Aoto tickled my ear with a stiffed smile"
"With the appearance of animal lust, the first time we laid together...."
What does 過ぎる actually mean?

Not what you're asking about, but isn't that first sentence more like "Aoto's stifled laughter tickled my ear"?

Firstly, 過ぎる potentially represents two different verbs すぎる and よぎる, and in your sentence is used よぎる. (Some people write すぎる as 過ぎる and よぎる as 過る, but it is not a strict rule, as what was found in your example.)
Secondly, the verb よぎる means “to pass in (front of)”, but its meaning here is also based on the expressions 心をよぎる, 頭をよぎる and something similar, which take some idea, thought, or memory as a subject, and means “to come to one’s mind/head for a moment”.
～のことが過ぎる can be interpreted as “the memory of ... pops up in my mind/head for a moment”
